# Is it possible to match node by id, that lies in the properties of other node or relationship?

Tags: neo4j, match

I've got a problem with simple matching. 
For example, 
I have some node

```
start startNode = node(0)
```

It has a relationship with another one. One of the relationship's properties is idOfThirdNode with id(thirdNode).

I found out that `start point = node( )` get only digits as arguments and any `toInt(rel.idOfThirdNode)` is not available at all, as other `match(point:_Node) where id(point) = rel.idOfThirdNode`

Find node by property is not a problem. But it isn't possible to set new duplicate id-property.

Have this problem any decision or only saving this property in model and begining of new matching with this property like id?

**Edit:**
Earlier I have had in result of such action:

```
start startNode = node({0})
optional match startNode-[r:REL]-(relNode: _Node)
return distinct startNode, id(r) as linkId, id(relNode) as nodeId, 
r.idOfthirdNode as point
```

beautiful table with nulls in some fields

```
______________________________________
| StartNode| linkId | nodeId | point |
--------------------------------------
| startNode|    1   |   2    | null  |
|   info   |        |        |       |
-------------------------------------
| startNode|    3   |   4    |   5   |
|    info  |        |        |       |
```

But now this "where" make disabled all null matching

```
 start startNode = node({0})
 optional match startNode-[r:REL]-(relNode: _Node), (pointNode:_Node) 
 where id(pointNode) = r.idOfthirdNode 
 return distinct startNode, id(r) as linkId, id(relNode) as nodeId, 
 collect({pointNode.name, id:id(pointNode)}) as point
```

and I get only second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
START startNode = node(0)
MATCH (startNode)-[rel]->(secondNode), (thirdNode:_Node)
WHERE ID(thirdNode) = rel.idOfThirdNode
RETURN startNode, secondNode, thirdNode
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
MATCH (point:_Node), (node:Label)
WHERE ID(point) = node.idOfThirdNode
RETURN *
```

But I've never actually seen that done because relationships are so much better than foreign keys